# High Load data transfer between fiware IoTAgent and Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have raised this issue to review the Environmental parameters for the use case of High loads and Multi service. Our use case is that we have three different Fiware service paths and send the High load requests. For this kind of use cases, do i need to chnage the environmental parameters like below

ORION_MULTI_SERVICE

ORION_NOTIF_MODE

ORION_MAX_CONN

My question is what I need to set for the above parameters for HighLoads and Multi service requirement. Please suggest.

We tried with 80k records per hour with 3 service paths and we are getting below errors.

ECONNRESET

EADDRNOTAVAIL

Comment: Which version of Orion are you talking about? Where are you getting the network error? When we talk about performance it is always necessary to specify the involved infrastructure.